# java tcp program too slow(on the same computer)

Tags: java, performance, sockets, tcp

So basically I am running 2 java application on my computer ad then after i transmit data i calculate speed of transmition over java tcp and speed is always around 7 MegaBits/second
i was expecting something atleast 56mbits/second anyway here is the client application :

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient
{
 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
 {


 System.out.println("Hello, World");


           String modifiedSentence;
           BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7);

           BufferedInputStream inFromServer  = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

           double count=0;
           OutputStream socketOutputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

        String s = "012345678901234567\n";    

        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(); 

        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        // socketOutputStream.write(bytes);
        // inFromServer.read(buffer);
        // modifiedSentence = new String(buffer);
        // System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
         socketOutputStream.write(bytes);
         long times=System.nanoTime() ;
        long temp=times;long temp2=times;
           while (true) {
               socketOutputStream.write(bytes);
           count++;

           socketOutputStream.flush();
               if(count>=100000){
                   break;

               }

           }

           times=System.nanoTime() ;
           System.out.println("time(ns) : " + (times-temp2));
           double speed=(72*2*count)/(double)((times-temp2)*Math.pow(10,-9));
           System.out.println("speed : " + speed/(1024*1024));
           clientSocket.close();


 }
}
```

and here is the server code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient extends Thread
{
    Socket clientSocket;
      public TCPClient(Socket socket) {
            super("KKMultiServerThread");
            this.clientSocket = socket;
            }

 public  void run() //throws Exception
 {


 System.out.println("Hello, World");
    try {

           String modifiedSentence;


           BufferedOutputStream outToServer = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
           BufferedInputStream inFromServer  = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

           double count=0;


        String s = "012345678901234567\n";    

        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(); 
        long times=System.nanoTime() ;
        long temp=times;long temp2=times;
        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 19;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

         modifiedSentence = "";
           while ((inFromServer.read(buffer))!=-1) {

          // outToServer.write(bytes);
         //  outToServer.flush();


           }

           System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);

           clientSocket.close();

     } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
         System.exit(1);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                            + "the connection to: taranis.");
         System.exit(1);
     }


 }


}
```

server code was adjusted not to write but only recieve and client to only send where through put is increased to 27Mbit/sec , but not 50Mbit/sec wich is half speed of ethernet , any help ?

Comment: I would benchmark different buffer sizes - 64k seems awfully large.

Comment: Changing buffer sizes didnt change throughput at all . weather increasing or decreasing it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with LJ2.

To increase throughput, resize you buffer to something like 1024 bytes and send the same amount of data; you are currently sending 18 bytes only; this is not really efficient.
Also, consider reading on one side only... you're doing a ping-pong match (client reads and writes afterwards, same goes for the server) - that doesn't help if it comes to throughput.

Comment: sending large data(64k or more) or sending small data at each loop(1-2 bytes) at at time doesn't matter with throughput , i will try having one side receive only and see the difference.

Comment: Making server only recieve and client sends have increased my throughput to 27Mbit/sec but thats it , what else do you think would be the problem ?

Comment: Oh yes, it makes a big difference, especially if you're not using the loopback address. Think about all the overhead being involved to marshal the data as a TCP and IP package and back again. It's like putting a fully loaded [matchbox car](http://www.matchbox.com/) or a fully loaded truck on the road.